# Using Show() to display data from another class

Tags: c#

I know how to create programs in C++, but very new to C# so be patient, but I have a question, and for the life of my couldn't find it on google, or stackoverflow search (maybe didn't know a good way to phrase it). I have two functions on my form: A `NumericUpDown`, and a `Button`. When the button is clicked, I want to grab the data from `NumericUpDown`, and `.Show()` it in a message box. Here is what I currently have.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StatBox_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //decimal Stat = StatBox.Value;
        //string StatStr = Stat.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(StatBox.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(StatBox.Value.ToString());` - is what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. Now to figure out how to close the question :)

Comment: You are very welcome!  In order to ''close" the question, just accept one of the two answers you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like C++, C# is a strongly-typed language. That means that you will get a compile-time error if you try to pass an `int` to a function that accepts a `string`, or vice versa. That's what is happening to you here.

[The simplest overload of the MessageBox.Show function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/519bytz3.aspx) accepts a single `string` parameter, yet you've passed it a `decimal` (the result of [`StatBox.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value.aspx)):

```
MessageBox.Show(StatBox.Value);
```

The fix is simple: convert the `decimal` to a `string`. All .NET objects provide a `ToString` member function that can be used to obtain a string representation of the object. So rewrite your code like so:

```
MessageBox.Show(StatBox.Value.ToString());
```

You can even get fancy and concatenate a number of sub-strings together when calling this function, just like you can with the C++ `string` type and I/O streams. For instance, you might write this code:

```
MessageBox.Show("The result is: " + StatBox.Value.ToString());
```

or use the [`String.Format` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx), which is somewhat similar to the C `printf` function. Then you can specify a [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) or [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) numeric format and avoid calling the `ToString` function explicitly. For example, the following code will display the number in the up-down control in fixed-point notation with exactly two decimal places:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The result is: {0:F2}", StatBox.Value.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void StatBox_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //decimal Stat = StatBox.Value;
       //string StatStr = Stat.ToString();
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(StatBox.Value.ToString());
   }
}
```

Since you are using a `MessageBox` to `.Show()` the data, you will want to call the `.ToString()` method on the `StatBox.Value`.

PS - Welcome to SO!  You will love it here.